# Is a method invoked by P/Invoke running in the same thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, mono, pinvoke

I have a native library written in C. Here's a simple function for example:

```
int my_test_method(int value) {
  return value * 2;
}
```

I have also declared this method in a C# P/Invoke class:

```
[DllImport("helloworld.so", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int my_test_method(int value);
```

If I call this function in a secondary thread, will the native code be executed in the same thread? i.e. if the native function is thread safe, will this method run in parallel without blocking the other threads?

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
  int value = my_test_method(2);
});
```

Bonus: Is this true for .NET and Mono, under Windows, Linux, OSX, iOS and Android?

Comment: the threading is not impacted by the mere call, why should it, pinvoke also works in a single threaded environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The native function will be executed on the same thread that called the managed P/Invoke method.

If you call the managed P/Invoke method on a background thread, that's the thread that the native function will be executed on.

This is true for all versions of .NET and Mono, under Windows, Linux, iOS, OSX, Android, Windows Phone, and probably a few others I've forgotten about as well.